# Edge giving Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CSS3116) error for font files from same origin (within double iFrame)

Tags: html, css, iframe, cors, microsoft-edge

I have a web application hosted on AWS which works fine when accessed normally - lets say https://example.cloud.net/webApp

Another web site has an iFrame that points to a specific page on the web application that also contains an iFrame (lets say https://example.cloud.net/webApp/iFrame). This iFrame points to the original login but with some querystring parameters (https://example.cloud.net/webApp?view=integration&client=otherWebApp).

So in essence the other web application has an iFrame within an iFrame. It was done in this way to get around some login issues and should be assumed that this cannot be changed as part of a solution.

Everything works perfectly fine with this "double iFrame" solution on all browsers (including IE 11) except Edge. On Edge some of our self hosted font files are not loading and the below errors are appearing on the browser console:

```
CSS3116: @font-face failed cross-origin request. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
d0123456.font-abcd.ttf

CSS3116: @font-face failed cross-origin request. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
543211e.font-abcd.woff
```

which then leads to

```
CSS3120: No fonts available for @font-face rule
```

and a lot of missing icons

The font files are referenced from within the css using relative URLs. For example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work, especially since it works on all modern browsers except Edge

Comment: did you try to add enable cors (cross origin ...) ? Are you using asp.net mvc???

Comment: I shouldn't have to enable cors, I am accessing resources from the same origin. No I am not using ASP.net

Comment: I think you can solve this by enabling cors first with * settings then narrow down options one by one till this font file i.e .toff or .eot

Comment: If it is a CORS issue why does it work in IE, Chrome and Firefox? These browsers recognise that the domain is the same. To me it seems like there is a setting on Edge that needs to be changed, or it is a bug in Edge

Comment: @Neil Did you ever manage to figure out the issue with Edge? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: No sorry I never got to the bottom of this, personally I think it is an issue with Edge since it worked with all other browsers

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the prompt reply. I agree, I think it's Edge as well.

Comment: Man, this is from back in 2017, and it's still broken!

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/edge-cant-load-any-web-pages-after-win-10-october/8e985039-1bc0-4586-93ce-1be0af14733a?page=2